# How can i copy the contents of a range to the bottom of another on the same google sheet tab?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a tool where I want to be able to show a current change order for a client in one section and then have a record of that change order for the future in the columns next to it.

In Col B:D, i would enter information, and then when i want to submit i would run a function that would copy the contents of B3:D10 into F:I.

I know how to accomplish this if I involve another tab

somethig like this:

currentTab.getRange("A3:D10").copyTo(anotherSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,1,6), {contentsOnly:true});

and then i could reference that tab in my log.

I really want to keep everything local to this tab, but I cant figure out how to do it paste to the bottom of any range that I want instead of the whole tab.

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a more detailed input (making the input multiple row entries or at least 3 dummy entries)? Also, kindly include your desired output since the output table from your sample image is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "Copy") {
    let vs = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 4).getDisplayValues().flat().join('\n')
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 7).setValue(vs);
  }
}
```

[image]